# Проблема при декомпиляции .NET

Tags: c#, .net

После декомпиляции .NET в классах вылез непонятный `<module>`, что это? Компилятор ругается на скобки.

[image: img]

Comment: Декомпиляция официально не поддерживается фреймворком .NET. Предъявляйте претензии к разработчику декомпилятора (если он коммерческий).

---
Я бы предположил, что этот модуль написан на C++/CLI, он не может быть корректно декомпилирован в C#.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если это .NET, то это не значит, что это C#.

В стеке языков .NET есть такие, которые позволяют создавать переменные вне всяких классов (VB.NET), или же создавать функции/процедуры вне классов (VB.NET, IronPython), или же полностью функциональные (F#). Такие переменные/функции/процедуры будут находиться в Module.

C#, насколько мне известно, не ипользует Module в силу своей ОО. Исключение составляет тот случай, когда код обфусцируют - обфускатор может активно использовать эту часть программы, чтобы запутать код еще больше.